# Spring Boot + HSQLDB/H2 always displays 'port was already in use' on Windows 10

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, hsqldb

I am developing a Spring Boot application and I'm receiving the following error when I try to run the application with a embedded database(HSQLDB or H2, in-memory or file), even with the port not being used:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-9080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:234) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:179) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at br.com.mixavionics.GsmApplication.main(GsmApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1042) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:573) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1035) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

I've tried the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` option, changed ports, disabled the firewall too, unsuccessfully (I'm the admin of the machine). On my Linux machine (Linux Mint) the application (using HSQLDB/H2) runs fine without errors, and running the application on my Windows 10 machine with a MySql server the application runs OK too...

I'm missing something?

**My application.properties file:**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.password = sa
```

**My pom.xml dependencies:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the HSQLDB/H2 is still running. Can you kill the process of all java apps and try to run again?!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong.

Try changing the port. If that doesn't work - turn off firewall.

I hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your Spring Boot configuration, it's probably a matter of privileges; could you run your IDE as an Administrator? Also, if you are running the application from the terminal, try running Command Prompt as an Administrator and then try running the app.

Comment: I'm the admin of the machine... running the application from the IDE and the terminal - same problem.

Comment: Even if you're the admin, you still have to run Command Prompt/IDE with `Run as Administrator`

Comment: Hmmm, that helped solve all of my issues... Is Java added as an exception to your firewall?

Comment: I've tried with the firewall enabled and disabled, same problem :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm really out of my depth here, in my case those issues were caused by lacking privileges and firewall :( Maybe your hosts file is corrupt, or maybe having Microsoft Loopback Adapter installed has messed something up or maybe installing the adapter may help (really grasping at straws here)